# How to save a function to a dictionary entry?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code, Its a slice of my main dictionary I use for my game

```
GAME_DICT = {
    # Player Media, Colors, And Locations
    'BLUE': {
        'COLOR': g.BLUE,
        'PLAYER_IMAGE': m.MEDIA['blue_face'],
        'BULLET_IMAGE': m.MEDIA['blue_bullet'],
        'LOCAL': 220,
        'ABILITY':         # Issue
        }
```

Currently, I want to add a function as a value into the dictionary.
Python spits out a syntax error when I try to add a function using `def function_name:` and when I create a function from outside the dictionary and just save it to an entry it raises an error needing all the args to be filled, which I don't want as I need to fill in specific things as the args when I call this in another file. Any help?

Comment: If your function is a one-liner, this is what `lambda`s are for. If not, define it the normal way on one line, then assign it separately. (Needs to be `def  function_name():` if it takes no args, ofc -- leaving out the argument list will cause a syntax error no matter what).

Comment: That said, this question would be greatly improved by showing the code for your actual attempts that fail, and what errors they fail with. See the docs on building a [mcve].

Comment: Alright, Ill make some edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the name of the function in a dictionary without incident.

If you have:

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x * 2
```

You can also have:

```
d = {'funcname': myfunc}
```

You make a named function using the `def` statement.  You can also make a nameless function using the `lambda` statement.

```
d = {'funcname' : lambda x:x * 2}
```

Once you create a function, you can use the name or the lambda reference like any other variable. So...

```
f = d['funcname']
print('Double is ', f(2))
```

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: @SnivyDroid   Sweet. Let me know if you've got any other related questions. I'm around for a little bit longer.